# WinRT, C#, canvas and children inertial scrolling

Tags: c#, canvas, windows-runtime

Situation: WinRT application, canvas on a main page. The canvas has a number of children. When user taps on canvas and moves pointer, I’m trying to scroll them. All works fine, but I don’t know how to emulate inertial scrolling.

The code:

```
private GestureRecognizer gr = new GestureRecognizer();
public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();


            gr.GestureSettings = GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateInertia;
            gr.AutoProcessInertia = true;
        }
```

I’ve subscribed to some canvas events:

```
//Pressed
private void Canvas_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Touch)
            {


                var _ps = e.GetIntermediatePoints(cnvMain);
                if (_ps != null && _ps.Count > 0)
                {
                    gr.ProcessDownEvent(_ps[0]);
                    e.Handled = true;

                    Debug.WriteLine("Pressed");
                }
                initialPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(cnvMain).Position.X;
            }
        }



//Released
private void Canvas_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Touch)
            {

                var _ps = e.GetIntermediatePoints(cnvMain);
                if (_ps != null && _ps.Count > 0)
                {
                    gr.ProcessUpEvent(_ps[0]);
                    e.Handled = true;

                    Debug.WriteLine("Released");

            }
        }

// Moved
private void Canvas_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (gr.IsActive || gr.IsInertial)
            {

                                   gr.ProcessMoveEvents(e.GetIntermediatePoints(null));


// Here is my code for translation of children
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

So, I can translate canvas children, but there is no inertia. How can I enable it?

Unfortunately, I can't use something like GridView or ListView in this app because of specific data.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`GestureRecognizer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241937.aspx) with [`ManipulationInertiaStarting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.manipulationinertiastarting).  This should give you enough information to implement inertial scrolling.

Comment: Another option would be to put your canvas inside a scrollview and let the scrollview handle the gestures.